# How can I get counts of buckets by their nested aggregations' values?

Tags: elasticsearch

Working on Elasticsearch 6.4.

My index is full of docs that have a `group_id`.

I want to group by the `group_id`, then aggregate within each group by a boolean value for `active`. I want to return a true if any doc within the group is active. (I think I can do this with a `max` aggregation, since the boolean `active` returns a 1 for true and a 0 for false on each document.

*Then* I want to do a count of groups that are "active".

So, at the end of the day, I just want an integer. Well, in the future, I'll want to repeat the process for some other boolean values.

Here's what I've tried:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "my_filter_terms": [
              "foo",
              "bar"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "includes": [],
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_group_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "group_id",
        "size": 10000,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "group_active": {
          "max": {
            "field": "active"
          }
        },
        "count_total": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              "total": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "group_id"
                }
              },
              "active": {
                "term": {
                  "group_active": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How can I get counts of buckets by their nested aggregations' values?

The "What I've tried" example didn't work.